# Program type already present ( duplicate class error)

Tags: android, build-error

After include bar-code scanner library. when I try to rebuild my app. I'm getting error **"Program type already present: com.google.gson.gsonNull"** 
I'm spending lot of time to resolve this issue but unable to resolve this. I've seen lot of question about this but could not found any solution.

I've try this on Android studio 3.2.1 and Android studio 3.1.3

I read official document of this error:  [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes)

I'm also figure out my duplicate classes (Retrofit and Scanner Library). But I don't want to remove any library either. So, I've started to exclude "gson" which is mention in different question's answer.

```
  configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
    }
```

that solve my problem but then I'm unable to call API's. Because its not converted to gson. Here my library that include duplicate classes.

```
  implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0"
  implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"
  implementation project(':barcode_scanner_library_v2.4.2.0')
```

I'm also try to exclude explicitly just like.

```
 implementation (project(':barcode_scanner_library_v2.4.2.0')){
            exclude module: 'gson'
  }
```

but this is not working.

This problem may be solve after I'm implement retrofit with jackson. But its time taking solution.